# Prove using continuity

Tags: continuity

$g(x)$ is a function with a fixed point $p$. If $g'(x)$ is continuous on $(p-\delta_0,p+\delta_0)$ for some constant $\delta_0>0$ and $|g^{'}(p)|<1$, then there is a positive number $\delta<\delta_0$ such that 
$$|g^{'}(x)|\leq k<1 $$
for some constant $k$ and for $x$ in $(p-\delta,p+\delta)$. Based on continuity 
$$|g^{'}(x)-g^{'}(p)|<\epsilon$$
for $x$ in $(p-\delta,p+\delta)$. How do I get to the expression 
$$|g^{'}(x)|\leq k<1 $$. 
I need some hints as I haven't done such proofs in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|g'(p)|<1$ the by continuity of the derivative at $p$ and for $\epsilon_0$ such that $|g'(p)|+\epsilon_0 <1 $ we have that $\exists \delta_1>0$ such that $||g'(p)|-|g'(x)|| \leq |g'(x)-g'(p)| \leq \epsilon_0$  for all $x \in (p-\delta_1,p+\delta_1)$

Thus for $k=|g'(p)|+\epsilon_0$ and $\delta < \frac{\min\{\delta_0,\delta_1\}}{2}$
you have the desired conclusion.